# How crypto token in metamask wallet get stolen by hacker?

Tags: cryptocurrency

My crypto token which runs in BSC network has just been stolen few hours ago. I looked at the transaction history in my metamask wallet, nothing new in there. So it must be executed remotely. I do not think the hacker got my secret phrase. I never share it to anyone. The only "sharing" I have done is when I import the secret phrase from my linux laptop to windows pc by using SSH. But I visited many dapp sites and approve some of them and left them connected. But AFAIK, approval is specific to a token. Say for example I approve a dapp to spend my token X for certain amount, it should not be able to spend my token Y. Or am I wrong? What methods could possibly be used by the hacker to take over my wallet and transfer tokens to his wallet?

Comment: Maybe your phone got hacked? What's BSC?

Comment: Probably the most common way crypto is stolen is via sim-swap.  So check any accounts related to your phone.  If you've ever copied/pasted something related to bitcoin, there's also malware/virus that targets clipboard contents for bitcoin.

Comment: I am not using a phone. I am using laptop running linux and a pc running windows. BSC is Binance Smart Chain.

Comment: Phishing attacks targeted at crypto site account holders is also common.  Ex: https://krebsonsecurity.com/2020/09/two-russians-charged-in-17m-cryptocurrency-phishing-spree/  (Maybe run through your old e-mails to see if you might have been sent a phish?)